# Set Picker data based on another Picker on screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a screen in my application which is used to allow admins to edit/create users. On this screen there is information which I have set, if the user exists, by overriding the `OnAppearing()` method.

```
        EmployeeFull fullEmployee = new EmployeeFull();
        fullEmployee.Employee = _employee;
        fullEmployee.Locations = await _clientBl.GetLocations();

        fullEmployee.SelectedLocationIndex = fullEmployee.Locations.FindIndex(x => x.LocationID == _employee.LocationID);

        BindingContext = fullEmployee;
```

On the screen, amongst other information there are two pickers, the first if set via the code above and shows the location information. If there user is currently at a location, it selected the `SelectedIndex` of the picker.

XAML Code for the two pickers:

```
    <!--Location-->
    <Picker ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding Name}"
            Title="-Select a Location-"
            x:Name="location_picker"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedLocationIndex}"
            SelectedIndexChanged="Location_picker_SelectedIndexChanged"></Picker>

    <!--SiteLocation (Populated from location choice)-->
    <Picker Title="-Select a Site-"
            x:Name="site_picker"></Picker>
```

When the user selects a value from the first picker, an `onchange` method is hit in the `.cs` however I don't know how to set the information in the second picker based off this.

Is there anyway you can set the binding data of a picker using it's name, much like you can do with `listView` etc?

EDIT: The preferred way to set up the second picker would be much like the first. I have a `selectedSitelocationIndex` integer which I would set using the `siteLocationID` against a user. I would then want to populate the second picker with all the site locations against the selected location in the first picker.

Comment: yes, you can either set a picker's properties directly, or via data binding.  You don't really give enough context in your question for me to provide an example of how you might setup your 2nd picker.

Comment: @Jason Preferably I'd prefer to set the information for the second picker much like I have the first, via data binding however I cannot think of a way to bind. Like I stated in the question, if there was a way to bind it such as how you bind data to a listview using the `x:Name` that would be great but I haven't been able to find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can set it. There are 2 ways to do that:

1.By binding ItemsSource in XAML

2.By setting ItemsSource in CodeBehind

**1st way:**

I would suggest you to create a separate ViewModel as per MVVM.

Name it **FullEmployeeViewModel.cs**

```
public class FullEmployeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]  string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    public bool _selectedLocationIndex { get; set; }
    public bool _employee { get; set; }
    public string _locations { get; set; }
    public string _secondPickerItemsSource { get; set; }
    #region properties



    public bool SelectedLocationIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedLocationIndex; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedLocationIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Employee
    {
        get { return _employee; }
        set { _employee = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public string Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
        set { _locations = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
     public string SecondPickerItemsSource
    {
        get { return _secondPickerItemsSource; }
        set { _secondPickerItemsSource = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    #endregion


    public FullEmployeeViewModel()
    {
        Employee = _employee;
        Locations = await _clientBl.GetLocations();
        SelectedLocationIndex = fullEmployee.Locations.FindIndex(x => x.LocationID == _employee.LocationID);
    }


}
```

Now,the XAML part

```
<Picker ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding Name}"
        Title="-Select a Location-"
        x:Name="location_picker"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedLocationIndex}"
        SelectedIndexChanged="Location_picker_SelectedIndexChanged"></Picker>

<!--SiteLocation (Populated from location choice)-->
<Picker Title="-Select a Site-"
        x:Name="site_picker" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondPickerItemsSource}"></Picker>
```

In your `OnAppearing()`

```
FullEmployeeViewModel  vm = new FullEmployeeViewModel ();
BindingContext = vm;

/**
You have select first item
**/

vm.SecondPickerItemsSource = //put your list here
```

**2nd way:**

```
async void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                site_picker.ItemsSource = "your list";

            }
        }
```

Comment: The 2nd way you provided seemed to suit me best. Setting the `ItemSource`, `ItemDisplayBinding` and `SelectIdex` in the `OnChange` method worked.

Comment: That's nice.
Just a tip, if your app will remain small with limited pages then 2nd way is okay , but you should really go with 1st way if your app will grow later and become complex.This way,you will follow MVVM pattern